# initialScrollIndex not working for FlatList react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am experiencing an issue with the initialScrollIndex of FlatList - the argument of initialScrollIndex is simply ignored and the first item is shown.

https://snack.expo.io/Bk1mkK0zZ

Comment: I tried the snack and it went to the correct position, 2. Perhaps the default Expo SDK or something else has changed since you first created it ??

Comment: Defining layout explicitly by setting `getItemLayout` callback helped me to fix the `initialScrollIndex` behavior

Answer (score 24):

I had the exact same problem, which is why I found your question. After a lot of testing, I found a workaround, which seems to work. Instead of using `initialScrollIndex` I used the function `scrollToIndex` once the list is rendered. Applying it to your code, it will look like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList, Dimensions, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    const data = [{id: 0},{id: 1},{id: 2},{id: 3},{id: 4}];

     return (
      <View onLayout={() => this.onLayout()}>
        <FlatList
          ref={el => this.list = el}
          data={data}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}

          pagingEnabled={true}
          horizontal={true}
          showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}

          getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}

          debug={true}
        />
      </View>
    )
  }

  onLayout() {
    this.list.scrollToIndex({index: 2})
  }

  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'lightblue', width: WIDTH, height: HEIGHT, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text style={{color: 'white', fontSize: 300, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{item.id}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  getItemLayout = (data, index) => (
    {length: WIDTH, offset: WIDTH * index, index}
  );
}
```

Hope it works for you.

By the way, putting `this.list.scrollToIndex({index: 2})` in componentDidMount, does for some reason not work for me, which is why I used `onLayout` instead

Comment: It is strange that passing in `initialScrollIndex` and `getItemLayout` is still causing problems. I am suprised it has not been fixed or documented better! When I render a FlatList using these two props it is rendered ok, but when I scroll up or down items do not render.

Comment: @Spliid Great! Work for me

Comment: @KarlTaylor 2019 and this is still such a pain

Comment: `this.list.scrollToIndex is not a function`

Answer (score 11):

Using RN 0.61.5

I've solved this with setting:

- `onContentSizeChange` which will handle scroll to index whenever flatlist data is changed and all items rendered ( you can handle how many items will be rendered on initial render with setting `initialNumToRender` if needed)
- `onScrollToIndexFailed` which is necessary to use when using `scrollToIndex` function:

```
<FlatList
    ref={ref => (this.flatList = ref)}
    data={dataArray}
    style={style}
    eyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
    onContentSizeChange={() => {
        if (this.flatList && this.flatList.scrollToIndex && dataArray && dataArray.length) {
            this.flatList.scrollToIndex({  index: dataArray.length - 1 });
        }
    }}
    onScrollToIndexFailed={() => {}}
    renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
        return (
            <Text>Stackoverflow Answer</Text>
        );
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Wow, using `onContentSizeChange` is the only trick that worked for me in a SectionList. Thanks!

Comment: Also worked fine for me. I was trying to use getItemLayout and initialScrollIndex but for some reason my list was not being updated after adding or removing values. Now it works.

Answer (score 8):

I used getItemLayout and every thing work like charm

```
const getItemLayout=(data, index)=> {
    return { length: wp(100), offset:  wp(100)* index, index };
}

<FlatList
        horizontal
        pagingEnabled
        initialScrollIndex={1}
        snapToAlignment={"start"}
        decelerationRate={"fast"}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        data={routes}
        getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
        renderItem={rowItem}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but my situation was a little different. In my case, I was starting off with a `WIDTH` of `0` and waiting for the `onLayout` event callback to set the correct width. Therefore, on initial render, it didn't matter what value `initialScrollIndex` was, it couldn't scroll with a zero width. Using `Dimensions` to set an initial width fixed it for me.

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the following:

```
pagingEnabled = { true }
```

This will fix your example.